# Xamarin.Firebase.Crash.42.1021.1 could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin, xamarin.android

[image]

I am trying to install Firebase crash reporting nuget package but it giving error. can you please explain how can i solve.

Comment: Please post any logs surrounding the errors you are getting in output.

Comment: i added pic please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target `MonoDroid,Version=7.0` in order to install this package. It's as simple as changing your `Target Framework Version / Compile With Version` to `7.0` or higher.

Comment: Thanks. @Jon Douglas